# Azure database requires firewall changes but are missing from settings

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I've seen several instructions (such as [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/)) explaining how to enable outside apps to connect to the Azure database.

[image]

The instructions always mention a Firewall option in the General Settings.

[image]

My Azure portal does not display "Firewall" in the General Settings. This seems to be preventing me from connecting from SQL Server.

When I try to connect to SQL Server from SSMS it says: "Your client IP address does not have access to the server. Sign into an Azure account and create a new firewall rule to enable access.

[image]

Then when I click "Add my client" or "Add my subnet range" it says "In progress..." and spins perpetually.

How do I enable access from SSMS (sql server management studio)?

EDIT:

On my screen I only see "SQL database" and not "SQL server". I wonder if that makes a difference? And how can I see the other one?

Also instead of the firewall link shown below I see something about Geo-replication role. Weird.

What would put me on that track?

Can SQL database only be seen from within Azure while SQL server can be seen from the outside? If so, I'm not sure how I would set up the schema, etc. I guess I could CodeFirst everything ...

[image]

**EDIT:**

OK, looks like there is a difference between SQL database option (from the left hand menu that says "SQL databases" and the VM-based SQL server option (from the virtual machine section on the left hand menu. See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-management-azure-sql-database-and-sql-server-iaas/).

Still not sure how to enable my IP or connect from Sql Server Management Studio ...

Comment: This has to be a bug in SQL Server Management Studio 2016 RC.

Answer (score 3):

I think you searched in Azure Database General setting. You have to **go to SQL Server**, there is an option for Firewall Setting you can add your Client IP Address.

**SQL Server:**

[image]

**SQL Database:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screen shots. For some reason I see "SQL database" where you see "SQL server". Also I see "Geo-replication role" where you see "Firewall".

Comment: By clicking  Server name it will redirect to "SQL Server".There you can see firewall option and then add your Client IP address